# visual studio c# actualizaciones con setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Buen día, tengo un programa hacho en **visual studio con C#** y el instalador generado con **setup Project**. Ahora necesito hacerle unas mejoras al programa, pero no se como generar las actualizaciones con el setup Project y no consigo información sobre eso.
**Como puedo hacer para generar las actualizaciones con Setup Project? hay forma de generarla e instalarla desde un pen drive o disco externo?**

Comment: No creo que sea posible actualizar una aplicacion usando msi. Deberás comprobar si existe la aplicación, desinstalarla e instalar la nueva

Answer (score 1):

Existe una forma una forma de indicarle al `Setup Project` que valide si debe actualizar

[Updates to setup projects](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay que prestar atencion en las propiedades cambiando `RemovePreviousVersions` a true y `DetectNewerInstalledVersion`

Comment: Desconocía esa opción, pero como decía en mi comentario, al final es desinstalar la versión antigua para instalar la nueva.  Buena respuesta de todas formas

Comment: si se reduce a desinstalar para proseguir con la instalacion de la actualizacion, lo bueno es que el setup detecta que hay una previa analizando el ProductCode, por eso es importante mantener siempre el mismo GUID para el producto

Comment: entonces de que manera podría generar solo las actualizaciones, sin necesidad de desinstalar e instalar nuevamente?

Comment: con Setup Project del VS no lo veo posible, quizas se podria evaluar InstallShield  https://info.flexerasoftware.com/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio o WIX https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension  pero la verdad es que no conozco tanto como para decirte si realizan una actualizacion sin desinstalar previamente